# The type or namespace name 'SharePointContextFilterAttribute' could not be found

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I created a fresh sharepoint add in but when i try to built it i get this error.
i addded the sharepointpnpcoreonline nuget package,but still error persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add **AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolkit** NuGet package - it should add missing files